# Unhandled exception in jquery-ui-1.10.0.js. 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am developing my ASP-MVC application in ie9, and when I load the first login page I get this error;

> Unhandled exception at line 6953, column 7 in
>   .../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js
>
> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

I look inside the JQuery-ui-1.10.0.js file and I find this code;

```
_search: function( value ) {
        this.pending++;
        this.element.addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
        this.cancelSearch = false;

            this.source( { term: value }, this._response() );
    },
```

I find that reason this happens is because;

```
this.source is set to null.
```

But I haven't been able to find out why this is and how to fix it.

I have tried to locate where this.source is set.
I found this code in jquery-ui;

```
_initSource: function() {
        var array, url,
            that = this;
        if ( $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
            array = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter( array, request.term ) );
            };
        } else if ( typeof this.options.source === "string" ) {
            url = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                if ( that.xhr ) {
                    that.xhr.abort();
                }
                that.xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: request,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        response( [] );
                    }
                });
            };
        } else {
            **this.source = this.options.source;**
        }
```

I have highlighted the code that is executed (ie the 3rd branch) and where this.source is set to null.
I have not been able to trace back any further than that.

My View Source is;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding a manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SCD</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico" />

    <link href="/dataTables/css/AutoFill.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/dataTables/css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/dataTables/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/dataTables/css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/dataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/dataTables/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/dataTables/css/TableTools.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/dataTables/css/TableTools_JUI.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/superfish-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <link href="/Content/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/sunny/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/demos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <section class="main-content">


<hgroup class="title">
    <span style="margin-left:40px;"><h2>Log in.</h2></span>
</hgroup>

<section>

<form action="/" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="I-FFb6bdAvkOOiAvXXU3kBC2f8ovY_xH2Y0tG4craWHUa6oVcHH-V6zi2kJy4luADvcRN6e_EC9vyIA8QnIWSnocZqnRFV79uVl_3s_BndjE_3R2P0MFJMpsLfA0yte4_N4hyNXQj3livH-2fNZGmKnZGQscE-Qj6GbSIRivn6A1" />        <div id="logon">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="UserName">User name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="geoffreypayne" /> 
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" /> 
                    <label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Log On" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
</form>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.calculation.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.columnizer.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.printElement.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/scd.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/dataservice.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/popupservice.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/supersubs.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/AjaxLogin.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jqprint.js"></script>

    <script src="/dataTables/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/dataTables/Scripts/TableTools.js"></script>
<script src="/dataTables/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script src="/dataTables/Scripts/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script src="/dataTables/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/scd-basket.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/scd-search.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/scd-companyDetail.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/SCD/LogOn.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/CapsLock.compressed.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using an autocomplete anywhere on your site? do you happen to have a live example of your site?

Comment: Yes I am using autocomplete, although not on this particular page which is the logon page. The site is not live.

Comment: Can you post your autocomplete code and or a demo on jsfiddle? jQuery version?

Comment: I have posted my View Source. As you can see, I am not using autocomplete on this page so I do not think it is relevant, although I could be wrong.

Comment: It depends, in one of your js includes can be the problem; can't you reduce a bit your code? With this can be difficult to help you

Comment: I shall have to try that. What it looks like is that for some reason the autocomplete attributes are being injected into every input field whether it needs it or not. Where it is needed, the autocomplete works fine. Where it isn't needed, the this.source = null which throws an exception.

Comment: I think the solution is to add a specific class to the fields that will host autocomplete "fieldSuggest" then use a more restrictive selector to attach autocomplete only to them; if ok I'll add this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current informations, I think the problem is that the autocomplete is attached to every input tag, and not for all there is a source option defined.

A possibile solution is to add a specific class to the fields that will host autocomplete `fieldAutocomplete` then use a more restrictive selector to attach autocomplete only to elements that have that class.

Like:

```
$( "input.fieldAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
});
```

Comment: I only just realised I had to click on the bounty icon to do that! I thought they were awarded automtically. I think you got your points now.

Comment: @arame3333 it's automatically gained when it is expired; you can do it manually to :-) Thanks and happy coding